# VBA PasteSpecial does Partial Paste

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a loop running which selects a range, copies and then pastes the values in the required columns:

```
Set wks6 = wkb.Sheets.Add
With wks6
    Dim rstCP As Recordset
    Dim firstCP As Boolean
    Dim previousPot As Integer

    Set rstCP = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("FUT_CR_Capacity_Count")
    firstCP = False
    previousPot = 0

    Do While Not rstCP.EOF
        If firstCP = False Then
            .Range("N3", "AA3").Copy

            .Range("AB" & rstCP![COuntWC] + 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            previousPot = previousPot + rstCP![COuntWC] + 3
            firstCP = True                                
        Else
            .Range("N" & previousPot + 1 & ", AA" & previousPot + 1 & "").Copy
            Debug.Print "N" & previousPot + 1 & ",AA" & previousPot + 1 & ""

            .Range("AB" & rstCP![COuntWC] + previousPot + 1).PasteSpecial _
               Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
               :=False, Transpose:=False

            Debug.Print "AB" & rstCP![COuntWC] + previousPot + 1
            previousPot = previousPot + rstCP![COuntWC] + 1
        End If
        rstCP.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

So the first part of the loop (`If firstCP = False Then`) runs perfectly fine; it copies the range N3 to AA3 further pasting the values in the range AA13 to AO13 automatically. However when the loop continues for all other increments (the else part of the if statement), it partially pastes the values from columns AA15 to AB15.

NOTE: I've tried specifying the range in the paste:

```
.Range(AA#,AO#).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
```

... but this does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "partially pastes the values"?  are the values in two columns truncated? Or is the `PasteSpecial` method only pasting these two columns?